# Redirect user to liferay login page using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, liferay

I want to redirect the users to the login page when some inter error has occured. Javascript function has got the response as internal error so from this javascript function I want to redirect the user to Liferay login page. what function should I call to achieve this?

Comment: So if you take all the liferay parts away, your question is basically how to redirect users using javascript. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `href` property of the `location` object when you need to redirect browser to a new page:

```
location.href = '/login/page';
```